# Does the wide call moves with the batsman?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a batsman moves in his crease, right or left, does the wide also moves with him? If a right-handed batsman moves to his right and leave the stumps and the bowler bowls a ball which is in the reach of the batsman but outside the wide line, Will this be a wide call or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, yes. If a batsman moves, the ball will based on *both* their current position and their normal position. Quoting from [Law 22 - Wide ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-22-wide-ball/):

> 22.1.1 If the bowler bowls a ball, not being a No ball, the umpire shall adjudge it a Wide if [...] the ball passes wide of where the striker is standing and which also would have passed wide of the striker standing in a normal guard position.

The effect of this is that a batsmen moving expands the area into which a bowler can bowl rather than "moving" the area.